# Angular $resource response is not treated as Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

My server is sending a response with Array inside of Array:

```
[
    [{1:1},{1:2}],
    [{2:1},{2:2}]
]
```

I'm not able to execute array functions on the internal array.
I'm able to execute `forEach` on the outer array, but not on the internal ones.

Here's my service:

```
return $resource('api/blablabla/:blablaId', {
        blablaId: '@_id'
    }, {
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
```

so far I've tried using:

```
myData=angular.toJson(myData)
```

and

```
myData=JSON.parse(angular.toJson(myData))
```

But it hasn't worked. In fact, they gave the following output:

```
{"0":{"1":1},"1":{"1":2}}
```

`angular.forEach` worked, but I need some other array functions too.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that response data will be array of array list, then you can iterate using below code. there is no need to convert it into json.

```
a.forEach(function(a1){
  a1.forEach(function(item) {
    for( var key in item ) {
      console.log(item[key])
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Please read the question. I said "I'm able to execute forEach on the outer array, but not on the internal ones."

Comment: but I am able to iterate internal array using forEach. 

I think you want to iterate objects inside internal array, then you need to use for-in.

Comment: no, I just want to iterate on the internal array.
$resource is converting the internal array to objects with `0, 1, 2...` keys